# How much water do nuclear plants release as steam?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

I'm not sure if this is the right site, but I was wondering how much water is released by today's nuclear plants during normal operation.

Comment: In an open circuit, the water returns to the source, a little further downstream, a little hotter. In a closed circuit, it's closed... Steam production is marginal compared to the water cooling

Comment: It's more of an engineering question and igael is correct, it depends on the construction of the power plant.